# Create a proxy server on my computer

Tags: proxy, server

I'd like to create two servers on my computer: one used as a proxy and another one on which there will be some Web applications. I'm a bit lost on how to do it. Can I only use `Apache` to do this?

I would then create a `Java` client that would establish a `WebSocket` connection between the server and itself, passing through the proxy server.

**EDIT**: why doing this? I'd like to try something.

Suppose you have Web applications in the cloud on one side and an employee's private computer on the other. 
They are separated by the proxy of the employee's company. I'd like to know if I can establish a `WebSocket` connection between the private PC and the Web applications located in the cloud so that they can exchange data.

Thing is, only the PC has the IP address of the Web application server, and not the opposite.
I thought about long-polling, but after research I saw it was a dirty trick and that `WebSockets` were the future. I want to try if I can establish this kind of communication. According to this [graph](http://cdn.infoq.com/statics_s2_20150902-03315u4/resource/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers/en/resources/websockets2.png), it is possible.

Comment: What should the proxy do? Just pushing bytes to-and-fro'? Or log/transform the data passed?

Comment: It would simply redirect the request coming from the client to the server. So the proxy needs to be letting passing trough the WebSocket protocol, which is another thing to handle.

Comment: So simple TCP forwarding would suffice?

Comment: If you need encryption, `stunnel` will do this.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't know very much in this specific area, so I'll let you be the judge. See updated original post.